# Can't connect to specific wifi 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I can't connect to specific wifi. It's connected but there's no internet.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zgb4FRHr58/

Comment: Which one? If you're talking about the "Meizu m3 note" hotspot then you should troubleshoot the Android phone itself. Typically it works just by rebooting the phone. If you connect once, disconnect then reconnect again without rebooting the phone then it typically doesn't work. Why, I don't know. Ask Meizu.

Comment: Qfact network. It's working on my other ubuntu laptop, also 16.04.

Comment: Please [edit] your question anytime you need to add to or correct the original post. That said, "Qfact" is using the worse possible wireless encryption settings - TKIP -, known to *not* work with some chips and their Linux drivers. If you can manage that network, change it to WPA2-AES only. If you can't manage that specific network then probably there's probably nothing you can do short of using other hardware.